# Word macros suddenly blocked

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, blocking, security-warning

I have a Word 2019 .docm file that contains a few macros that I wrote myself.

This file was "working" since several years fine until now. Today, I opened it and got a warning that the macros were blocked, and they indeed are unreachable (which is a little catastrophy for me).

The hints from Microsoft is to unblock the file in the properties or to declare the originating site as safe in the Trust Center, but this does not make sense as the file was never downloaded nor mailed.

What can I do to retrieve those macros ?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps suggested by Microsoft to unblock the file? What was the outcome?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke: I commented on that already, but check my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way, by declaring the *path* to that file as secure in the Trust Center:

File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations.

Comment: Such sudden policy changes are irking.

Comment: I believe the settings that restrict the use of VBA reflects the latest evolution of "macro-viruses" fluctuating in "the wild" - I have a growing suspicion (impression) that VBA is for virus-makers only. Not for us who'd like to use it for legit things.

Comment: @Hannu: mh, macro viruses have been around for a while. I already had to switch from .docx to .docm in the past for security reasons.

Comment: If it was just "policy" changes; I have a recent example where a dynamic reference setting suddenly was not allowed; a documented function could no longer be executed by code. From then; The reference has to be set manually, a static setting.

Comment: I have a similar problem, and I solved it through your method.